# Need help finding a book I read 5 or so yrs ago, written in the 90s. It was scifi romance type thing. YA

Tags: story-identification, virtual-worlds, underground-civilization

The book was about a girl who lived in a virtual reality (though I don't think she really remembered putting herself in it. while in her apartment she gets attacked, and somehow brought back to reality, by someone, a guy who claims to know her, and thinks of her as a traitor for going to the surface (the rebels, the ones who refused the virtual reality, lived underground) and for going to the virtual reality, more or less kidnap her and remind her of who she was, at least partly. She can't remember much of anything before the side switch. Anyway. I don't remember a lot because let's be real, I was way more concerned with the romance at that time than I was the story line. Lol. Help me out here. I really would love to read this book again and actually follow the story this time around.